# Static method call in generic manner

Tags: c#, inheritance, static-methods

I have multiple classes like:

```
public class Base { }
public class Base1: Base { public static List<Base1> LoadFromXml(string path) }
public class Base2: Base { public static List<Base2> LoadFromXml(string path) }
```

Then I want to have a method like this:

```
public List<T> PrepareBase<T>() where T: Base { return T.Load("C:\test.xml"); }
```

So that I don't have to make a method for every type.
But I don't know how to accomplish this or something similar.

The problem is that I can't make the LoadFromXml method known to the base class because static inheritance is not a thing. Neither is creating a seperate interface with a static method.

Is there a way to do this or am I expecting too much?

Edit:
An example of the LoadFromXml method:

```
public class Base1 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PropertyOnlyInBase1 { get; set; }
    public static List<Base1> LoadFromXml(string path)
    {
        List<Base1> baseList = new List<Base1>();
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
        foreach(var node in doc.Descendants("Base1"))
        {
            Base 1 base = new Base1() { ID = node.Attributes["id"] };
            base.PropertyOnlyInBase1 = node.Element("PropertyOnlyInBase1");
            baseList.Add(base);
        }
        return baseList;
    }
}
```

So the Base classes also have some unique properties. That's why I needed the inheritance thing in the first place.

Comment: Not possible.  static methods are bound to their defining class.

Comment: Why don't you make it an instance method if you want polymorphism?  Or a single generic static method that can return lists of different types?

Comment: How do you plan to call `PrepareBase`? And what do you want to do with it's output? (In other words... suppose you could do that - just as you wrote it. what does the statement that makes use of it looks like?)

Comment: @Amit: In my MainForm.cs Load Method: `this.base1List = PrepareBase<Base1>();` and use that list as a DataSource for a ComboBox. |

@DStanley It didn't seem logical to me that a method with no connection to the instance whatsoever should be an instance method.

Comment: @ManuelHoffmann I agree, but if you want polymorphism it may be necessary.

Comment: So if the call site knows the concrete type to call, and the concrete type of the return value, what's the value of the generic? just call the actual function directly.

Comment: Can you give some example code of how a LoadFromXml method is done? Probably the real problem is more about generic code reuse than about static methods.

Comment: @A.Chiesa Yes, it is precisely about code reuse. I said in the question that I don't want to write the same code for multiple "Base" child classes. I'll update my question with an example of `LoadFromXml`. | 
@Amit I want a generic method because I have to write a functionally identical method for each type that inherits from Base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my approach to the problem and solved it using the Factory pattern. I also provided each class with an instance method SetPropertiesFromXml to handle the custom properties. Unlike the previously used method, a method like that made sense as an instance method.

**Factory:**

```
public static class BaseFactory 
{
    public static Base GetBase(string id) 
    { 
        switch(id) { case '1': return new Base1(); ... }
    }

    public static T GetBaseList<T>(string xml, string tagName) where T: Base
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        var nodes = XDocument.Load(xml).Descendants(tagName);
        foreach(XElement node in nodes)
        {
            var base = GetBase(node.Attribute("id").Value);
            base.SetPropertiesFromXml(node);
            list.Add(base as T);
        }
    }
}
```

**Bases**

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public virtual void SetPropertiesFromXml(XElement node) 
    { 
        //<Set Properties like: this.Property = node.Element("key");>
    }
}

public class Base1
{
    public override void SetPropertiesFromXml(XElement node)
    {
        //<Set Custom Properties for Base1>

        //Call Base to add the normal properties as well
        base.SetPropertiesFromXml(node);
    }
}
```

**Call**

```
List<Base1> list = BaseFactory.GetBaseList<Base1>("test.xml", "Base1");
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add a `GenericBase`:

```
public abstract class Base
{
}
public static class GenericBase<T>
    where T : Base
{
    public static List<T> LoadFromXml(string path)
    {
        //Load from XML
    }
}
public class Base1 : Base { }
public class Base2 : Base { }

public class Test //MainForm.cs class or whatever you want
{
    public void Tester() //Load event handler or whatever you want
    {
        List<Base1> base1List = PrepareBase<Base1>();
    }
    public List<T> PrepareBase<T>() where T : Base
    { return GenericBase<T>.LoadFromXml("C:\test.xml"); }
}
```

**Edit:**

As [D Stanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081897/d-stanley) mentioned, it's not possible; but I made some work-around that could be helpful for you:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public static List<T> LoadFromXml<T>(string path) where T : Base, new()
    {
        List<T> baseList = new List<T>();
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
        foreach (var node in doc.Descendants(typeof(T).Name))
        {
            T t = new T();
            Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var item in node.Elements())
                d.Add(item.Name.ToString(), item.Value);
            t.Load(d);
            baseList.Add(t);
        }
        return baseList;
    }

    protected internal abstract void Load(Dictionary<string, string> elements);
}
public class Base1 : Base
{
    public string CustomProp1 { get; set; }
    public string CustomProp2 { get; set; }
    public string CustomProp3 { get; set; }

    protected internal override void Load(Dictionary<string, string> elements)
    {
        if (elements.ContainsKey("CustomProp1"))
            CustomProp1 = elements["CustomProp1"];
        if (elements.ContainsKey("CustomProp2"))
            CustomProp2 = elements["CustomProp2"];
        if (elements.ContainsKey("CustomProp3"))
            CustomProp3 = elements["CustomProp3"];
    }
}
public class Base2 : Base
{
    public string CustomProp1 { get; set; }
    public string CustomProp2 { get; set; }
    public string CustomProp3 { get; set; }
    protected internal override void Load(Dictionary<string, string> elements)
    {
        if (elements.ContainsKey("CustomProp1"))
            CustomProp1 = elements["CustomProp1"];
        if (elements.ContainsKey("CustomProp2"))
            CustomProp2 = elements["CustomProp2"];
        if (elements.ContainsKey("CustomProp3"))
            CustomProp3 = elements["CustomProp3"];
    }
}

public class Test //MainForm.cs class or whatever you want
{
    public void Tester() //Load event handler or whatever you want
    {
        List<Base1> base1List = PrepareBase<Base1>();
    }
    public List<T> PrepareBase<T>() where T : Base, new()
    {
        return Base.LoadFromXml<T>("C:\test.xml");
    }
}
```

Comment: I realised that I left out an important detail, so I added more information regarding custom properties in the different Base classes to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're correct that the class that loads these from XML should be separate from the class that's *being loaded*. As you said, it has no real connection to the instance.

Perhaps what you need is a separate class that loads those instances for you.

```
public class BaseXmlLoader<TBase> where TBase : Base
{
    public List<TBase> LoadFromXml(string filePath)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TBase));
        // Load your file and deserialize.
    }
}
```

The benefits aren't huge because it's not saving you that much code. But if the `LoadFromXml` methods are essentially the same except for the type then you're getting something out of it.

Comment: They're not _exactly_ the same.  `Base1` and `Base2` have one or two custom properties that are also loaded in the `LoadFromXml` method. That's why I tried to do it the inheritance way first.